# Problem with pagination links with routing

Tags: php, mysql, html, css, cakephp

i need to route all `/home/college`, `/home/school` etc to the`home` controller's `index` action, with the following prototype.

```
function index($type="school"){
...
}
```

below is my routing definition

```
Router::connect('/home/:type',array('controller'=>'home','action'=>'index'),array('pass'=>array('type'),'type'=>'(college)|(school)'));
```

i am also using pagination inside it. But when i generate the next and previous links it's like below

```
http://mysite.com/home/index/school/page:2
```

How can i remove the 'index' from the link?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you will have much luck removing `index` as it is the default action.

However, I'm surprised your route works as `mode` is undefined.

```
Router::connect('/home/:type',
  array('controller'=>'home', 'action'=>'index'),
  array('pass'=>array('type'), 'type'=>'(college|school)'));
```

Check out [CakePHP Routes Configuration](http://book.cakephp.org/view/945/Routes-Configuration).

Comment: im sorry there. it was not 'mode', it's `type`.

Comment: what if it's not index (let's say it's `home`)?

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, you could just create a 'dummy' `home` action, and call `index` with it.

```
function home($type="school"){
    $this->setAction('index',$type);
}
```

http://api13.cakephp.org/class/controller#method-ControllersetAction